# What we have to do after doing an act of kufr

Tags: kufr

I have done an act of kufr after realising it I have recited shahada 3 times and asked for forgiveness I have also promised to allah that I will not repeat it, does it is enough or I have to do something else , can I now continue as a muslim ,how we know allah has forgiven us
Please answer
I am scared can I marry a muslim after repeating or can I lead a normal life as a muslim after repeating

Answer (score 0):

I think a simple tawbah does the job right which includes ( AFAIK )

1. Fear or remorse or regret or being ashamed
2. Stop the sin right away
3. Never return to it
4. Seek his forgiveness with a sincere ( true intentional ) heart and that does the thing! And please upvote if this was helpfull

Allah Forgives All sins bro he forgave the man who killed 100 people

How do you know that your forgiven? Your life somehow changes positively. ..or your now able to stay away from it i think..Jazak Allah